# A weird linear algebra Question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let
$$Q = q^T I$$ and $$Z = q f,$$ where $q$ is an $N\times X$ lower-triangular matrix, and $I$ and $f$ are $N \times 1$ vectors.

Is there any way to express $Z$ as a function of $Q$?
In case it helps, $q$ has all elements between 0 and 1, and $I$ is all 1's.

To give some background, this is part of a linear program I am trying to solve. The choice variable is $q$, but I cannot obtain an analytic characterization (which I need). However, if by some stroke of luck I can optimize directly with respect to $Q$ and then I could find an appropriate $q$.

Thank you!

Comment: Using $I$ for a vector of $1$'s is rather unfortunate, because to (almost) the whole world, $I$ stands for the identity matrix :P To answer your question, in general, no, because, as you can check, very different matrices $q$ will give you the same vector $Q$. These entries are just the column sums of $q$. So if $f$ encodes different information, it's hopeless.

Comment: Since $I$ is all $1$s, $Q$ is just (the transponse of) the sum of the rows of $q$. There is really no reason why this information should be sufficient to determine $qf$, not even with some dependence on $f$. (also, $f$ must be $X\times 1$ for the thing to make sense)

Comment: For instance, solve this, if you can: let $x,y\in [0,1]$ such that $x+y=\frac14$. Find $(xf, yf)$.

Comment: Thank you @Sassatelli and @Ted!